# Custom UIViewController transition where UITableViewCell grows to full screen and back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I haven't been able to find any examples of this online. How can I achieve the following effect? Instead of the standard slide-to-left effect when tapping a table row, I'd like the view controller transition animation to look like the following:

1. User taps a cell in the table
2. The cell starts growing to fill the screen, pushing other rows above and below it "offscreen".
3. As the cell grows, cells elements (text, images, etc.) cross-fade into the new view's contents until the new view completely fills the screen.

I'd like to also be able to interactively transition back into the table view by dragging up from the bottom edge, such that the reverse of the above is achieved. i.e. view starts shrinking back into a normal table view cell as the "offscreen" cells animate back into position.

I've thought about taking a snapshot of the table and splitting it up at the points above and below the cell, and animating these snapshots offscreen as part of a custom view controller transition. Is there a better way? Ideally I'd like to not take snapshots, as I may want to have animations, etc., still happening in the table view rows as they fade offscreen.

Comment: you may check this out https://github.com/aberger/ABMExpandingTableViewCells

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, i have seen your post today and his is written in swift programming language.
the follwing code is to expand the selected cell to the full screen, where the subviews will fade out and background image will expands.

First complete     cellForRowAtIndexPath, then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath,

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    isSelected = true 
    selectedCellIndex = indexPath.row

    tableView.beginUpdates()

    var cellSelected: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cellSelected.frame = tableCities.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    println("cell frame: \(cellSelected) and center: \(cellSelected.center)")
    let newCell = cellSelected.frame.origin.y - tableOffset
    println("new cell origin: \(newCell)")

    var tempFrame: CGRect = cellSelected.frame
    variableHeight = cellSelected.frame.origin.y - tableOffset
    tempFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.height

    println("contentoffset: \(tableView.contentOffset)")
    let offset = tableView.contentOffset.y
    println("cell tag: \(cellSelected.contentView.tag)")
    let viewCell: UIView? = cellSelected.contentView.viewWithTag(cellSelected.contentView.tag)
    println("label: \(viewCell)")
    viewCell!.alpha = 1

    UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, delay: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState, animations: {

        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, offset + self.variableHeight), animated: false)
         tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, self.variableHeight, 0)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        cellSelected.frame = tempFrame
        viewCell!.alpha = 0
        println("contentoffset: \(tableView.contentOffset)")



    }, completion: nil)


}
```

then update your heightForRowAtIndexPath, as

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if isSelected && (selectedCellIndex == indexPath.row) {
        return self.view.frame.height

    }else {
        return 100
    }

}
```

Ignore this if already solved. and this might be helpful to others.

Comment: What are tableOffset and variableHeight  variables?